# Why objectdatasource is executing obsolete method without any error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, obsolete

ObjectDataSource is not recognizing obsolete method and executing it as normal method.

ObjectDataSource is not identifying the obsolete attribute where as the code behind file recognizes the obsolete method and throwing an error during compilation/build.

```
public class TEST
{
    public TEST()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    [Obsolete("Old method", true)]
    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Desc");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow drow = dt.NewRow();
            drow[0] = "Name_" + i.ToString();
            drow[1] = "Desc_" + i.ToString();

            dt.Rows.Add(drow);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

ASPX

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True"></asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="TEST"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>
</form>
```

ASPX.CS

[image: Code behind page throwing an error for obsolete method]

Am I missing any settings here? Please help and let me know if additional information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @rene answered, this attribute is more of a friendly reminder, not an enforced restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the markup is not *compiled* at design time.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
                      runat="server" 
                      SelectMethod="GetData" 
                      TypeName="TEST">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

So no compiler is invoked when you add or edit the value in the `SelectMethod` attribute, hence no error or warning is raised.

In the description of the [ObsolteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/961hff5d(v=vs.110).aspx) we find:

> Initializes a new instance of the ObsoleteAttribute class with a workaround message and a Boolean value indicating whether the obsolete element usage is considered an error.

Key is here the word *usage*. When the method is used in a declarative and/or late bound manner the compiler couldn't detect it's usage hence no error is raised. The method is still compiled and present in the assembly. There will no runtime exception be raised.

An `ObjectDataSource` instance uses reflection to invoke the method. Deep inside its bowels you'll find this (simplified):

```
Type type = this.GetType(this.TypeName);
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(this.SelectMethod, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
objectDataSourceResult = method.InvokeMethod(this, null);
```

Which basically lookups the method at runtime and invokes it. You can even change the value of `SelectMethod` during runtime and the code will still work. The obsolete attribute is not taken into account once the assemblies are compiled.

Comment: Thanks rene. Currently am changing the obsolete method access specifier from "Public" to "Private" so that objectdatasource could not find the specified method at run time. Is it the right approach?

Comment: If that fits your scenario, sure. Another option is to throw an exception for example `throw new InvalidOperationException();`. But you will run into those when you run your app. Not while you are developing your application.